# Prevent drop event to propagate to the parent if an inner droppable does not accept the draggable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a droppable `div#space` and a collection of draggable `li.element`. When I drag an `li.element` in the `div#space` a new `ul.group` is created, the `li.element` is appended to the `ul.group` and finally the `ul.group` is made droppable.

Given

I would like these elements to behave as follows:

1. when an `li.element` is dropped in the `ul.group` that **does not contain** it, the `li.element` will be added to the `ul.group`
2. when an `li.element` is dropped in the `ul.group` that **does contain** it, the `li.element` will be reverted to it's original position
3. when an `li.element` is dropped in the `div#space` (outside a `ul.group`) an new group is created as mentioned above.

The problem is that when an element is dropped on an `ul.group` that does not accept it the parent `div#space` will catch the event and will create a new group.

The `ul.grpup` has an *accept* function that checks if the droppable is an *element* and if it's not already been dropped.

```
newULGroup.droppable({
    drop: ...
    accept: function(ui)
    {
        var isElement = ui.hasClass('element')
        var elementId = '.' + ui.data().id
        var isAlreadyPresent = $(this).find(elementId).length > 0
        return isElement && (!isAlreadyPresent)
    },
    greedy: true
});
```

How would you implement this behaviour if not by accepting everything and ignoring things in the drop handler? (I haven't tried but I guess that would work)

---

*Edit*

### An attempt to fix it

I patched the jquery-ui-1.8.4.js to pass the event to the accept function. Now I can stop the propagation with `$(event).stopPropagation()`, but I have to animate *manually* the draggable helper back to its original position to simulate the revert, then remove it from the dom.

```
accept: function(ui, event)
{
    var isCriteria = ui.hasClass('criteria')
    var criteriaId = '.' + ui.data().id
    var isAlreadyPresent = $(this).find(criteriaId).length > 0
    var accepted = isCriteria && (!isAlreadyPresent)
    if (event && !accepted)
    {
        $(event.target).animate(ui.offset(), {complete: function() {$(this).remove()}})
        $(event).stopPropagation()
    }
    return accepted
}
```

Unfortunately it seems to destroy the *draggable* behaviour from the original element as well. Why, oh why?

Comment: I'm almost there: I patched the jQuery code to pass the event to the accept function. In there I called `$(event).stopPropagate()`, but it was stopping also the draggable helper to revert to the original position. So I animated it and removed after... but now the original `li.element` is not draggable anymore!!! Help!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve similar behavior, although using undocumented jQuery.ui feature.

If you look into the `jquery.ui.draggable` implementation (at least for v1.8.16) the `revert` option can also be a function. It has `this` being the draggable element, single parameter which is the droppable who accepted the drop, and return value is a `boolean` to indicate whether to revert the draggable or not.

So in your case you need to

1. have your `div#space` and `ul.group` always accept drops and be greedy
2. do the check in the ul.group `drop` handler and processes item only if it's not in the group yet
3. do similar check in the draggable `revert` function and revert itself if it's already in the group.